# Increment the value of a key?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this:

```py
i = 1
for item in cart:
    data_ps['itemId' + i] = item
    i += 1
```

But Python returns me an error: `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.`

Any idea how to increment the value of a key in a dict?

Comment: `data_ps['itemId' + str(i)] = item` - cast `i` as String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `'itemId'` is a string and `i` is an integer, and they can't be added without some form of manipulation, like `'itemId' + str(i)`.

If you have a relatively recent version of Python (3.6 or better), `f-strings` provide a nice way to do this<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
i = 1
for item in cart:
    data_ps[f"itemId{i}"] = item
    i += 1
```

---

However, since it appears that you start from `1` regardless, there's a good chance you're creating a dictionary `data_ps` from scratch each time rather than adding to it. If that *is* the case, you can use dictionary comprehension to do this in a one-liner (the second line below):

```
>>> cart = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
>>> data_ps = {f"itemId{i+1}":cart[i] for i in range(len(cart))}
>>> print(data_ps)
{'itemId1': 'apple', 'itemId2': 'banana', 'itemId3': 'carrot'}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> They have the advantage over string concatenation and `string.format()` in that they read better: the item that goes *into* the string is right there in the string itself, at the point where it will go. Contrast the line below with those following and you'll see what I mean:

```
tmpFile = f"/tmp/{user}_tmp_{os.getpid()}_dir"

tmpFile = "/tmp/" + user + "_tmp_" + os.getpid() + "_dir"
tmpFile = "/tmp/{}_tmp_{}_dir",format(user, os.getpid())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
i=1
for item in cart:
    data_ps['itemId' + str(i)] = item
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also another way you can do it, and helps in case you are more familiar with C/C++:

```py
i = 1
for item in cart:
    data_ps["itemId%d" % i] = item
    i += 1
```

Where **%d** means to insert an integer value in this position